# How can i get the CPU usage for an Azure app service using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-metrics-advisor

I need to get some metrics for Azure an app service . Values are the CPU (in %) and Memory consumed ( in %). I want to report if for example the CPU is high for a certain period of time , in order to give an indication that the app service is consuming high memory or resources and then send an email .

I am currently using

```
Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId 
"/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/Default-Web- 
 EastUS/providers/microsoft.web/sites/website2" -DetailedOutput -MetricName 
"BytesSent,CpuTime"
```

But from this how can i get the % CPU and % Memory. Or is there a different Powershell command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To get the CPU usage for an Azure app service using PowerShell:***

There is an Azure PowerShell command called `Get-AZMetric` to get all the metrics data from a particular resource (Eg: App Service). However,  **`CPU %`** is not a supported argument for `Get-AZMetric`, if you copy the `resourceID` of the Web App properities as it is a cloud service ID.

We can achieve it for overall `AppServicePlan` as `CPU %` supports here.

If the app services hosted in premium, standard and basic plans, `CPU%` will comes because of scaling out feature whereas `CPU_Time` is helpful when hosted in free or the shared app service plans.

```
get-azmetric -resourceID "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<AppService>" -MetricName "CpuTime"  -DetailedOutput
```

[image]

*After investigating, I've found a way to achieve it with the help of AppServicePlan by taking resourceID as shown:*

[image]

```
 az monitor metrics list --resource "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<AppservicePlan>" --metrics "CpuPercentage","MemoryPercentage"
```

***Metrics for CPU Percentage:***

[image]

***Metrics for Memory Percentage:***

[image]

***Note:***

1. Check the supported metrics through portal by clicking on
   **`"Diagnose and solve problems"`** if needed.

[image]

2. [Issues with AppService environments](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14190)

Comment: Jus a few question in regards to this .  It retrieves the CPU and Memory Percentage on the App Service Plan. The json data that comes back has about 15-20 rows , so i assume it must extract a number of averages ? Also where can i view these values in the Portal ? Is it under the App Service Plan ? I need to identify the app that is consuming cpu and memory and eventually is auto restarted. I want to capture the app that is consuming high CPU and Memory for lets say 15-20 mins and send an email before it restarts or stops . Is that possible with the commands you gave above in Powershell ?

Comment: 1. It is extracting the percentage averages of CPU & Memory. 
2. Yes, you can check all these metrics under serviceplan. `AppServicePlan -> Metrics`.
3.  To identify the app that is consuming CPU and memory: I suggest you to associate one webapp with one AppServicePlan. Then if we retrieve the metrics of serviceplan, it is nothing but we are extracting the webapp metrics. @Tracey

Comment: Yes I agree with that ,  but I have at most 3 app services in each app service plan. At the moment al i need to know is if the cpu and memory are high for the app service plan for a period of time. For example the cpu is at 95% for the last 30min. That means there is a bottleneck  and if i can read that in powershell , then i can send an email for admin to look at in the portal.

Comment: Also in the Json response to the command above , under timeseries -> data , there are a number of average fields ? Timestamp from 02:54-03:53 , so i assume it has taken the last hour worth of results . So if the average field is null then ignore , else I can take the value , the values range from 0.08 - 17.5 . So i assume that is min CPU % of 0.08 to max 17.5 ?

Comment: Yes we can list out the data by using filter parameter for a particular time. [Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: And if within that hour of data if it is consistently at lets say 80% , then I can assume that there  is an app in the App Service Plan causing an issue , so i need to grab all the json data from the command returned ?

Comment: Yes exactly. That is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249651/discussion-between-tracey-and-jahnavi).